# Delay in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-adapter, android-recyclerview

I am setting values in `adapter` of `recyclerView` like bellow :

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {

        String name, langId, type, lang, courseCategoryName;
        if (shortTermCoursesModels.get(position).getName() != null
                && !shortTermCoursesModels.get(position).getName().isEmpty()) {
            name = shortTermCoursesModels.get(position).getName();
        } else {
            name = "---";
        }

        if (shortTermCoursesModels.get(position).getLanguageSymbol() != null
                && !shortTermCoursesModels.get(position).getLanguageSymbol().isEmpty()) {
            langId = shortTermCoursesModels.get(position).getLanguageSymbol();
        } else {
            langId = "fa";
        }

        if (shortTermCoursesModels.get(position).getType() != null
                && !shortTermCoursesModels.get(position).getType().isEmpty()) {
            type = shortTermCoursesModels.get(position).getType();
            if (type.equalsIgnoreCase(context.getString(R.string.live))) {
                type = context.getString(R.string.title_live);
            } else if (type.equalsIgnoreCase(context.getString(R.string.one_lesson))) {
                type = context.getString(R.string.title_one_lesson);
            } else if (type.equalsIgnoreCase(context.getString(R.string.modular))) {
                type = context.getString(R.string.title_modular);
            }
        } else {
            type = "---";
        }

        if (shortTermCoursesModels.get(position).getCourseCategoryName() != null
                && !shortTermCoursesModels.get(position).getCourseCategoryName().isEmpty()) {
            courseCategoryName = shortTermCoursesModels.get(position).getCourseCategoryName();
        } else {
            courseCategoryName = "---";
        }

        switch (langId) {
            case "fa":
                lang = context.getString(R.string.Persian);
                break;
            case "en":
                lang = context.getString(R.string.English);
                break;
            case "ur":
                lang = context.getString(R.string.Urdu);
                break;
            case "ar":
                lang = context.getString(R.string.Arabia);
                break;
            case "az":
                lang = context.getString(R.string.Azari);
                break;
            case "tr":
                lang = context.getString(R.string.Turkish);
                break;
            case "fr":
                lang = context.getString(R.string.France);
                break;
            case "es":
                lang = context.getString(R.string.Español);
                break;
            case "id":
                lang = context.getString(R.string.Indonesian);
                break;
            case "ha":
                lang = context.getString(R.string.hausa);
                break;
            case "ru":
                lang = context.getString(R.string.Pусский);
                break;
            default:
                lang = "";
                break;
        }

        boolean reverseLayout = langId.equalsIgnoreCase("fa") || langId.equalsIgnoreCase("ur") || langId.equalsIgnoreCase("ar");
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams paramsTxtSubject = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) viewHolder.txtSubject.getLayoutParams();
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams paramsTxtTypeCourse = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) viewHolder.txtTypeCourse.getLayoutParams();
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams paramsTxtLang = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) viewHolder.txtLang.getLayoutParams();
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams paramsTxtCourseCategoryName = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) viewHolder.txtCourseCategoryName.getLayoutParams();
        if (reverseLayout) {

            paramsTxtSubject.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
            viewHolder.txtSubject.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
            viewHolder.txtSubject.setPadding(30, 0, 30, 0);
            viewHolder.txtSubject.setText(name);


            paramsTxtTypeCourse.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
            viewHolder.txtTypeCourse.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
            viewHolder.txtTypeCourse.setPadding(30, 0, 30, 0);
            viewHolder.txtTypeCourse.setText(type);

            paramsTxtLang.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
            viewHolder.txtLang.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
            viewHolder.txtLang.setPadding(30, 0, 30, 0);
            viewHolder.txtLang.setText(lang);

            paramsTxtCourseCategoryName.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
            viewHolder.txtCourseCategoryName.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
            viewHolder.txtCourseCategoryName.setPadding(30, 0, 30, 0);
            viewHolder.txtCourseCategoryName.setText(courseCategoryName);
            try {
                FontCustoms.setFontCustomTVBold(context, viewHolder.txtSubject, langId);
                FontCustoms.setFontCustomTVNormal(context, viewHolder.txtTypeCourse, langId);
                FontCustoms.setFontCustomTVNormal(context, viewHolder.txtLang, langId);
                FontCustoms.setFontCustomTVNormal(context, viewHolder.txtCourseCategoryName, langId);
            } catch (Exception ignored) {
                Throwable t = new Throwable(ignored).fillInStackTrace();
                FirebaseCrash.report(t);
            }
        } else {
            paramsTxtSubject.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
            viewHolder.txtSubject.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
            viewHolder.txtSubject.setPadding(30, 0, 30, 0);
            viewHolder.txtSubject.setText(name);

            paramsTxtTypeCourse.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
            viewHolder.txtTypeCourse.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
            viewHolder.txtTypeCourse.setPadding(30, 0, 30, 0);
            viewHolder.txtTypeCourse.setText(type);

            paramsTxtLang.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
            viewHolder.txtLang.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
            viewHolder.txtLang.setPadding(30, 0, 30, 0);
            viewHolder.txtLang.setText(lang);

            paramsTxtCourseCategoryName.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
            viewHolder.txtCourseCategoryName.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
            viewHolder.txtCourseCategoryName.setPadding(30, 0, 30, 0);
            viewHolder.txtCourseCategoryName.setText(courseCategoryName);
            try {
                FontCustoms.setFontCustomTVBold(context, viewHolder.txtSubject, langId);
                FontCustoms.setFontCustomTVNormal(context, viewHolder.txtTypeCourse, langId);
                FontCustoms.setFontCustomTVNormal(context, viewHolder.txtLang, langId);
                FontCustoms.setFontCustomTVNormal(context, viewHolder.txtCourseCategoryName, langId);
            } catch (Exception ignored) {
                Throwable t = new Throwable(ignored).fillInStackTrace();
                FirebaseCrash.report(t);
            }
        }

        Glide.with(context)
                .load(shortTermCoursesModels.get(position).getImageUrl())
                .placeholder(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.not_image))
                .error(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.not_image))
                .centerCrop()
                .into(viewHolder.imgCourseImage);


    }
```

In some device when I scroll list it has a little delay. What can I do for this delay?

Comment: In some device when I scroll list it has a little delay.

Comment: Too much string comparison...